# Load Word for Big Endian

Tags: assembly, mips, endianness

I'm a little confused as to how something like 'load word' works on Big Endian. On Little Endian if you `lw`, say, from where a label is pointing at (e.g. MIPS) load word would start 'reading' from RAM from the lowest address (first bit of first byte would have 2^0*(0/1) weight, then 2^1(0/1) etc..

Now, how does this work in Big Endian if the same label points at the most significant byte? Would the first bit it reads have (let's assume WORD is 4bytes and unsigned) 2^31 weight and then start going backwards, till we reach the last bit, essentially doing the same thing with Little Endian in reverse?

If someone could explain how the end value would be 'calculated', I'd be grateful. I am probably missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly how it would work, yes. Big endian is what we humans use everyday, that should be the easier one to understand :) E.g. 1234 in decimal, the 1 is the most significant digit, the thousands. 2 is hundreds, 3 is tens, 4 is ones. The value is 1*1000+2*100+3*10+4*1. Similarly for binary,  byte0*2^24 + byte1*2^16 + byte2*2^8 + byte3*2^0.

Comment: After a few months with MIPS and QtSpim big endian feels more unnatural to me! :P So, to sum it up, with Big Endian we still start loading/storing from the byte with the lowest address still, except now going up in addresses means going down in weight. And also, for instance, if I wanted to do the equivalent of `li 0x1234` of a little endian machine, in a big endian one and get the same value, I'd still have to make it `li 0x1234`, right?

Comment: Yes; when we use numbers in assembly language the assembler will translate so that number value is obtained.  If you load word data (`lw`) from `lab: .word 0x12345678` you'll get 0x12345678 in the target register.  The assembler will do the right thing knowing little vs. big endian.  If we were to use 4 individual `.byte` directives instead, we would have to concern ourselves with byte order (and alignment, too as `.word` knows to use `.align 2`).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!